# issue running mvn eclipse:eclipse on platform tag 4.0.3

Tags: wso2

I have checked out the platform 4.0.3 tag, and have hit an issue with the `SecVerifier` when running `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

I've cleaned the maven cache for `SecVerifier`:

```
rm -rf %USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository\org\wso2\carbon\SecVerifier
rm -rf %USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository\org\wso2\carbon\integration
```

Then tried `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`:

```
C:\wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_tags_403>mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:SecVerifier:4.0.0 (C:\wso2\src\wso2carbon_platform_tags_403\products\integration\security-verifier\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:integration:pom:4.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

I found this JIRA: [link](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14039), and applied the fix. Similar error:

```
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:SecVerifier:4.0.0 ... has 1 error
...
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact   
org.wso2.carbon:integration:pom:4.0.0 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log maven cannot find the parent pom.xml file since it is unavailable on the given location. You can check your checkout code and figure out the actual location and set the relative path correctly.
This need to be work correctly but due to some changes done by users sometimes builds can be break.

Hope this might help you.

Thanks.

Comment: The cause of this kind of error is people commit their changes to released branches and tags by mistake. This type of errors get fixed once found.

Comment: Just out of interest, are there any plans to use git in the future with CI workflows to prevent this sort of error making its way into the main repo? (e.g. see [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141385/80059](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141385/80059))

Comment: Chris, for your information currently in WSO2 we are planing on implementing new svn structure to avoid this kind of mistakes. This will be completed soon. Yes currently there some sources available on git, but it is yet to be completed.

Comment: FYI from Carbon 5.0.0 which is known as C5, WSO2 planing to use git for version control and as source code management (SCM). Currently we are working on that road-map.