# wso2 - so many maven issues when building from source

Tags: wso2

I have tried many different combinations of tags and branches, and none of them seem to build successfully first time around.

**Question**: Is this a known problem when building WSO2 products?  If lots of errors are expected, then I know that it's not necessarily me doing something wrong.

**EDIT:**

Some of my previous stackoverflow posts:

- [wso2 maven issue building platform patch release 4.0.9 - failure to find org.wso2.appfactory:wso2appfactory-parent:pom:1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431254/wso2-maven-issue-building-platform-patch-release-4-0-9-failure-to-find-org-wso)
- [issue running mvn eclipse:eclipse on platform tag 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400158/issue-running-mvn-eclipseeclipse-on-platform-tag-4-0-3)
- [What are the steps needed to build WSO2 Carbon Platform Patch Release 4.0.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432465/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-build-wso2-carbon-platform-patch-release-4-0-x)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your requirement. Do you want to build any specific product or a feature ? what is the maven version which you are using ? --Hasitha

Comment: I've added a few of my previous problems to the question.  These are only a few that I have recorded on stackoverflow.  There are may issues I run into that I haven't posted on SO.  The main problems seem to be: (1) parent pom location issues and (2) artefacts not being available in the wso2 maven repository.

Comment: patch release 4.0.9 is not a released branch. that is why you are getting first error. Manoj has already answered to your last question. Can you try to build 4.0.3 using branch link (not tag) by following instructions given by manoj.

Comment: @HasithaAravinda - Where can I check to see what branches have been released?

Comment: you can find carbon release matrix from [1]. But it is not updated recently. [1] http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finally building a product (Identity Server) from platform branch 4.0.0, I can say: **building from source can be difficult**.  I think this is mainly because:

1. The code base is huge
2. Code, files, etc may be checked into svn in a broken state

You have to be prepared when things go wrong to hunt down the problem and have a go at digging in the code, build files, etc to resolve the issue.

When I get a chance, I will put some instructions together which walk through a complete checkout and build of platform from scratch, because I think this will be immensely useful for others wanting to build a product.